# Angular HttpClient adding trailing slash on path with period

Tags: javascript, angular, http, httpclient

I'm trying to do an api request but the http service seems to mess up the api path.

When I add query params it puts a trailing slash between the path and the params and thus failing the request:

```js
if (params) {
    reqOpts.params = new HttpParams();
    for (let k in params) {
        reqOpts.params = reqOpts.params.set(k, params[k]);
    }
}

return this.http.get('https://my-api.com/v1/something.svc/resource', reqOpts);
```

The result I expect is this:

```
https://my-api.com/v1/something.svc/resource?param1=value
```

But instead what I see in the request is this:

```
https://my-api.com/v1/something.svc/resource/?param1=value
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tested it without the period in "something.svc" and it works fine, it only breaks when adding the second period.

Answer (score 0):

Please use an object format to pass param to an http get request.

Please update your http request code as below.

`return this.http.get('https://my-api.com/v1/something.svc/resource', {params:reqOpts});`